# Create UITableView in a VC with 2 Custom Columns UITableViewCell, load custom data from an array to the cell, Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

How to create the following `UITableView` in a `VC` with 2 Columns? As `UITableView` only has one column. Is it possible to do it in StoryBoard? How to add shadow, round the corners and add the blurish borders as in the pic? All help or pointer is greatly appreciated.

[image: pic]

## Edited

How to set the 2 columns in Objective C? I can't find any help over the net especially for objective C. I think both the columns are `UILabel`.

As for the rows, do I need to set the Prototype Cell to 3 at Story Board?

The 1st column will have static values: NAME, DATE OF BIRTH, LOCATION. The 2nd column will fetch data from an array [John Doe, 06.03.1991, New York]

Do I create a loop to insert the data?

## ANSWER

I followed this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mv_ohYBqzr4) and managed to create 2 custom `UILabel` columns and insert the columns from `NSMutableArray`

I can't get the following suggested answer to work, the answer suggested that we create an Empty User Interface and then add a `Table View Cell` and associate it back to the VC. I can't get it to work.
  Mine was just creating the 2 labels at the prototype cell at the `TableView` and then following the link above.

Comment: just create a simple customcell for your view

Comment: What is the prototype Cell for, do I need to set it to 3? Is it just add 2 label at the prototype cell at the storyboard?

Comment: wait write a answer for your help..

Comment: you know about customcell?

Comment: Not really, sorry

Comment: hey buddy you there

Comment: I am going through it, thank @RealmOfFire.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168085/discussion-between-realmoffire-and-hansheung-cheah).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a customcell and put 7 `UILabel` first 4 label gives name basic setting,NAME,DOB,LOCATION than remain 3 label set blank and give tham property in cell.h file

```
 #pragma mark tableview delegate

    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
        return [yourdataarray count];
    }

    -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

        TableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"yourcustomcellname"];
        if (cell == nil) {
            // Load the top-level objects from the custom cell XIB.
            NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"yourcustomcellname" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
        }
       id object = [yourdataarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSMutableArray class]]) {
        NSMutableArray *Array = (NSMutableArray *)object;
        //your cell property use here for fatch like below
          [cell.NAME setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[Array objectAtIndex:i]]];//here i=which index your array contain name data
    }
        return cell;
    }

    -(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
        return yourcustomcellheight;
    }

    -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    }
```

refer this tutorial for customcell
https://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/

Comment: wait sharing a custom cell tutorial because you dont know about custom cell

Comment: Hi @RealmOfFire, is this tutorial a custom cell tutorial? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o_VsUK3mmPw

Comment: @HansheungCheah yup that one is custom cell tutorial

Comment: Thanks @RealmOfFire

Answer (score 0):

You need to use custom `UITableViewCell`, it seems the first column is just a `label` and the second column is a `textfield`.

In order to add boundary and add corner

```
myTableViewCell.contentView.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor grayColor] CGColor];
myTableViewCell.contentView.layer.borderWidth = 1;
myTableViewCell.contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;
myTableViewCell.contentView.clipsToBounds = YES;
myTableViewCell.contentView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

check following example as a reference to learn how to create Custom UITableViewCell and use.

https://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-customize-uitableview-storyboard/

Answer (score 0):

These columns you need to design in UITableViewCell. It can be anywhere of your preference, storyboard or xib. 
For storyboard your view will be like this.

[image: storyboard cell]

you need to add tags for all the components you add into the cell

[image: tag for label 1]

[image: tag for label 2]

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    ...
    ...

    UILabel *label1 = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    label1.text = @"NAME";
    UILabel *label2 = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:200];
    label2.text = @"John";

    ...
    ...

    return cell;
}
```

The same way if you create xib your custom cell should be like this.

[image: xib custom cell]

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
StackTableviewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = (stackTableviewCell*)[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"StackTableviewCell" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    ...
    ...
    label1.text = @"NAME";
    label2.text = @"John";
    ...
    ...
}
```

For cell UI

```
self.lable1.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
self.lable1.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:169/255.0 green:169/255.0 blue:169/255.0 alpha:0.8].CGColor;
self.lable1.layer.borderWidth = 1;
self.lable1.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
self.lable1.clipsToBounds = YES;
self.lable1.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```